# Error when creating a Matrix or installing a Plugin

Tags: database, craft-pro, mysql, setup

We have 2 computers with a new Craft Pro trial installation. The files are exactly the same on both computers. We both use the same DB with the same `db.php` config settings.  We can both see the site and login to the `/admin` section.

The only issue is that on 1 computer I can not create a Matrix field or install a plugin. Then I get the error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLLATE=' at line 8
```

The other computer has no problem creating a Matrix field or installing a plugin. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are the installs on two separate servers or are they on the same box? What version of MariaDB? Can you share the whole SQL statement that's trying to execute?

Comment: Installations are on 2 different laptops, each have their own local environment. MariaDB Server version: 10.1.10

Comment: The specs of the one with the issue: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) PHP/5.6.17 - MariaDB Server version: 10.1.10.
On this link you will find the full debug output: http://pastebin.com/rFRRHvGU

Comment: Actually, the DB is on a separate server that both laptops connect to. MySQL version: 5.6.26. But when I move the DB to my local MariaDB and connect to it I still have the same issue.

Comment: We made a var_dump the method $this->setText($this->getConnection()->getSchema()->createTable($table, $columns, $options)); in file craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php. On the computer with the issue we see CHARSET= COLLATE=. On the other computer we see: CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci . see full var_dump here: http://pastebin.com/qYk0Lu7i

Comment: I just installed fresh copy of Craft on the laptop and in this fresh installation there is no issue with creating a Matrix field or installing a plugin. The CHARSET=utf8 and COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci. So I really wonder why this issue occurs in the craft project that I pulled from the repository and not in a fresh installed one.

Comment: Are you setting these to empty strings in your `craft/config/db.php` file maybe? https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php#L43-L51

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have a `db.php` file here:

```
craft/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php
```

If not, [download a fresh copy of the version of Craft you're using](https://craftcms.com/support/download-previous-versions) and replace your `craft/app` folder with the one you just downloaded.

This file was missing in my Git repository because the `.gitignore` file was set to ignore all `db.php` files on the site, not just the one they wanted to ignore in the `craft/config` folder.

If that's the case, make sure your .gitignore file uses a line like this:

```
craft/config/db.php
```

Instead of just this:

```
db.php
```